# C++ multithread program I/O problem with std::endl

Tags: c++, multithreading, io

I try to learn how to use C++11 thread library and then, I am confused about the output of my following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mtx;

void thread_function()
{
    std::cout << "Inside Thread :: ID = " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread threadObj1(thread_function);
    std::thread threadObj2(thread_function);

    if (threadObj1.get_id() != threadObj2.get_id())
        std::cout << "Both threads have different id" << std::endl;

    threadObj1.join();
    threadObj2.join();
    std::cout<<"From Main Thread :: ID of Thread 1 = "<<threadObj1.get_id()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"From Main Thread :: ID of Thread 2 = "<<threadObj2.get_id()<<std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I attach every std::cout with std::endl in order to flush the buffer and output the '/n' character. However, finally I got the output as the following.

```
Both threads have different idInside Thread :: ID = Inside Thread :: ID = 
0x700003715000
0x700003692000
From Main Thread :: ID of Thread 1 = 0x0
From Main Thread :: ID of Thread 2 = 0x0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

It seems that the '/n' before the Inside Thread disappeared. Could you please help me figure it out? Thank you so much!

Comment: Where is `'\n'` in your code?

Comment: `threadObj1.get_id()` is useless after `threadObj1.join()`.

Comment: I am sorry for that. It seems that it is not the problem.

Comment: @S.M. 'std:endl' will flush and output a character of '\n'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I should also receive three '\n' right?

The three `'\n'` characters in question *are there in your output.*  They're at the ends of the first three lines of output.

I think maybe you misunderstand what this line from your example means:

```
std::cout << "Inside Thread :: ID = " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
```

There are four separate function calls explicit in that one line of code.  That one line does exactly the same thing as these four lines:

```
std::cout << "Inside Thread :: ID = ";
auto id = std::this_thread::get_id();
std::cout << id;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Even assuming that the `std::cout` object is fully synchronized, You have done nothing to prevent the various threads from interleaving the separate function calls.  E.g.,

- main thread calls `std::cout << "Both threads have different id";`
- threadObj1 calls `std::cout << "Inside Thread :: ID = ";`
- threadObj2 calls `std::cout << "Inside Thread :: ID = ";`
- main thread calls `std::cout << std::endl;`
- threadObj1 calls `std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id();`
- threadObj1 calls `stc::cout << std::endl;`
- etc.

Comment: Thank you for your patient explanation first. I know what you mean is that my calls of "std::cout" are interleaved together and the order is just like what you have shown as the above. One more question. How can I avoid this case? So, I can use mutex to lock the data to the standard output in order to make sure that there is only one thread which can access the standard output. Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 threads which are accessing `cout` without any synchronization. You have defined `mtx` but it is not used, why?

Add lock_guard to protect cout statement:

```
void thread_function()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk{mtx};
    std::cout << "Inside Thread :: ID = " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

    if (threadObj1.get_id() != threadObj2.get_id())
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk{mtx};
        std::cout << "Both threads have different id" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I am a new one in the field of C++ multithread program. Can I understand that the problem is caused by race condition? However, even though the three threads access cout without synchronization, I think I should also receive three '\n' right?

Comment: @Sean There are no data races here because `std::cout` is thread safe. But you are issuing several write instructions to `std::cout` and the outputs are getting *interleaved*. One thread is writing to `std::cout` after the other thread printed its text but before its `std::endl`.

Comment: @Galik So,cannot we name this behaviour as data race to output of console ? In normal running of program we want to see line after line, not *interleaved* lines.

Comment: @rafix07 Technically what we have here is called a "race condition" rather than a "data race", here is a link explaining the difference: https://blog.regehr.org/archives/490